# Using jQuery DataTables plug-in in MVC3 with jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use the DataTables jQuery plug-in in MVC3 using an ajax request as the data source for the table.

I have a View called "Search" which contains a search form...under the form, I have the following html...

```
<table id="caseTable" class="clear full-width dataTable">    
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case Name</th>
            <th>Court</th>
            <th>Case Number</th>
            <th>Case Filed Date</th>
            <th>Chapter</th>
            <th>Last Researched</th>
            <th>Disposition</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the search form is submitted, an ajax call is sent off the get the tr elements for each record to be displayed in the table.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SearchForCases",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        CaseNumber: caseNumber,
        DebtorLastName: lastName,
        Last4SSN: last4SSN,
        FullSSN: fullSSN,
        StartDate: $("#StartDate").val(),
        EndDate: $("#EndDate").val(),
        SelectedCourtDistrictId: $("#SelectedCourtDistrictId").val(),
        SelectedChapterId: $("#SelectedChapterId").val()
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#caseTable > tbody").html(result);
        $("#caseTable").dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "asStripClasses": ["white-highlight"],
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });
        $("#caseTable > tbody > tr").dblclick(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("white-highlight").addClass("yellow-highlight");
        });
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#ajaxProgress").dialog('close');
        $("#searchResults").show();
    }
});
```

Everything loads up fine on the first call, but on subsequent calls, the data returned from the ajax call is being appended vs replaced.  I have checked the html being returned from the ajax call and it's always returning one row of data, `<tr><td></td></tr>` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the bDestroy option to remove the old datatable formatting first. You could also try removing the bRetrieve option.

```
   success: function (result) {
        $("#caseTable > tbody").html(result);
        $("#caseTable").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "asStripClasses": ["white-highlight"],

            "bDestroy": true
        });
```

**Edit**

If possible, it might be better to change your code so you can use the built in datatable ajax functionality by passing in the [sAjaxSource](http://datatables.net/usage/options) option when creating the datatable. This would require you to change your server side code to return json of data instead of html.

If that isn't possible, then you should use [fnClearTable](http://datatables.net/usage/options) to clear the existing data before adding the new data.

```
var dataTable;

$.ajax({

    ...

    success: function (result) {
        // If it has been created, clear the existing data in the datatable
        if(dataTable != null) {
            dataTable.fnClearTable();
        }

        // Add your new data
        $("#caseTable > tbody").html(result);

        // Create / recreate the datatable
        dataTable = $("#caseTable").dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "asStripClasses": ["white-highlight"],
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });

        $("#caseTable > tbody > tr").dblclick(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("white-highlight").addClass("yellow-highlight");
        });
    },

    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried adding that option but still got the same results.

Comment: Can you try removing the bRetrieve option and see if that does anything?

Comment: I removed the bRetrieve option and I am getting different results.  The datatable re-draws successfully on subsequent requests, however the rows don't stretch to the entire width of the table and subsequent calls append rows instead of replacing what is currently in the table.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix the issue with this solution?

Comment: Ensure that you have a '>' between #caseTable and tbody when getting the table element. I don't see one in your question. Also ensure that you are actually returning valid html from your ajax request. It will have to include the <tr><td>...</td>...</tr> tags since you are just replacing the html of the tbody.

Comment: You are correct that I was missing the '>' between #caseTable and tbody but it still didn't solve the issue when I fixed it.  I double-checked the html coming back from the ajax call and it returns one row of data every time, <tr><td>...</td>...</tr> tags only.

Comment: I fixed the width problem by setting "bAutoWidth: false".  Still looking into the issue with the rows being appended vs replaced on subsequent searches.

Comment: I completely missed the fnClearTable() funtion when looking at the documentation on the website...everything working as it should now.  Bounty is yours as soon as i can award it...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try initializing your datatable outside of the success callback and then just call the `fnDraw()` function to redraw the table after you have updated the html of the table.

**EDIT**

```
var dataTable = $("#caseTable").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": //Url to hit to query your database and return table data
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "asStripClasses": ["white-highlight"]
        });

$("#caseTable tbody tr").dblclick(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("white-highlight").addClass("yellow-highlight");
        });

$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SearchForCases",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        CaseNumber: caseNumber,
        DebtorLastName: lastName,
        Last4SSN: last4SSN,
        FullSSN: fullSSN,
        StartDate: $("#StartDate").val(),
        EndDate: $("#EndDate").val(),
        SelectedCourtDistrictId: $("#SelectedCourtDistrictId").val(),
        SelectedChapterId: $("#SelectedChapterId").val()
    },
    success: function () {
        dataTable.fnDraw();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#ajaxProgress").dialog('close');
        $("#searchResults").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Kevin - Thanks for the response.  I tried moving the initialization to the top of the script file and then calling the fnDraw() function after updating the html but it clears out the table.  I also tried calling it before re-loading the html and I get the data but no styling.

Comment: can you instead refactor your code to use serversideprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for the poor formatting but just add this condition in your code. This will ensure that of your table already exists and you are just going from one page to another then your data will be replaced and not appended. Hope this helps

```
if(typeof datataTable !="undefined" && datatable != null)
{ 
    $.ajax({

    success: function (result) {
    // If it has been created, clear the existing data in the datatable
    if(dataTable != null) {
        dataTable.fnClearTable();
    }

    // Add your new data
    $("#caseTable > tbody").html(result);

    // Create / recreate the datatable
    dataTable = $("#caseTable").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "asStripClasses": ["white-highlight"],
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });

    $("#caseTable > tbody > tr").dblclick(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("white-highlight").addClass("yellow-highlight");
    });
},


});} else{dataTable.fnClearTable(0);dataTable.fnDraw();}
```